# Flash PNG Quality on Tween

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, png, tween

In Flash I have some PNG images, and I wish these images to become 50% larger on hover. However the tween I have used to make them larger distorts the quality of the images considerably.

For the tween I am not using any external libraries and I am using a standard scaleX tween.

Is there a way around this loss of quality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, start with images that are of the largest size they'll ever be, and scale them DOWN from there.  So in your case, the normal size of the images will be 50% larger than they are now, which is how they will appear when hovered-over.  When they are not hovered over, scale them down by 33%.

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure the bitmap.smoothing is set to **true** - I think this makes the flash smooth the bitmap even when scaling down.